# How to convert the elements of a python list of lists?

Tags: python, list, type-conversion

I have a python list (`vals`) containing lists of strings like this:

```
[['540.0 ', '0.0 ', '0.0 ', '162.0 ', '2.5 ', '1040.0 ', '676.0 ', '28 ', '79.99 \r'], 

['540.0 ', '0.0 ', '0.0 ', '162.0 ', '2.5 ', '1055.0 ', '676.0 ', '28 ', '61.89 \r'], ...]
```

When I want to convert its elements with the code below, I get the following error:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float`

```
vals = [[float(item) for item in rec] for rec in vals]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: this is a *list* not an array

Comment: Anyway, your code works with the data you've provided. Presumably, there is some string in your data somewhere which cannot be converted to a float. You can handle that in several different ways that are really up to you and your particular use-case

Answer (score 0):

Palliative solution :
Not really optimized

It keep only dot and numeric

```
vals = [[float("".join(_ for _ in item if _.isdigit() or _ == ".")) for item in rec] for rec in vals]
```

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't work for me, got the same ValueError

Comment: @ZoltánOrosz Send original array pls and stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Casting to `float` from `str` allows white spaces but not alphabetical characters. A rough solution is `str.strip` to remove the undesired characters, either at the start or at the end of the string.

```
l = [['540.0 ', '\r0.0 ', '0.0 ', '\r162.0 \r', '2.5 ', '1040.0 ', '676.0 ', '28 ', '79.99 \r'], ['555']]

new_l = [[float(s.strip('\r')) for s in lst] for lst in l]
print(new_l)
# [[540.0, 0.0, 0.0, 162.0, 2.5, 1040.0, 676.0, 28.0, 79.99], [555.0]]
```